# How to implement a robust truncate method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, math, truncate

I know .NET has one built-in but it's an external call. Anyone knows why?

But the actual question is how to implement a truncate from scratch where the user will be able to specify how many digits to keep? Is multiplying a number by say 100 and then dividing it by the same amount enough? Or is there a better implementation?

Something like:

```
Truncate(12.3456789, 3);
// returns 12.345
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to look at IEEE floating-point integers.

You can then use `unsafe` code to modify the numbers, like:

```
unsafe
{
    double* pValue = &value;
    var asLong = *(long*)pValue;
    do whatever you want with asLong, e.g. bit-masking it, etc.; 
}
```

As to the 'why': I have no idea, though the [Shared Source CLI](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) may provide clues. My *guess* would be that it might be because of performance optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way:

```
var x = 1.2345678;
var tr = 4;

var truncated = (int) (x * Math.Pow(10, tr)) / Math.Pow(10, tr);
```

would give 1.2345;

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could do it this way.

Comment: @JoanVenge You say that, and yet you ask if it's possible in the OP itself.  This is simply the implementation of that approach.  *"Is multiplying a number by say 100 and then dividing it by the same amount enough?"*

Comment: No it's not. I didn't mention any powers.

Comment: @JoanVenge 100 is 10^2, thus it would be used to truncate to 2 decimal places.

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't pay attention to it but I thought he was raising the actual number to the power, that's why I thought it was a different method. Yeah if this works, then it's what I thought.

Comment: That's what happens when you use poor quality variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. In C++, and I think in C# as well, you could get the integer part of a floating point number by casting it to an integer type.

```
double Truncate (double num, int dig)
{
    if (dig > 15) dig = 15; // Don't overflow
    long p = Math.Pow (10, dig);

    // Save the integer part, so that we don't overflow
    long integer_part = (long)num;

    // Fractional part * 10^dig
    double frac = (num - Convert.ToDouble(integer_part)) * p;
    long frac_trunc = (long)frac;

    // Final result
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(integer_part) + (Convert.ToDouble(frac_trunc) / p);
    return result;
}
```

> Is multiplying a number by say 100 and then dividing it by the same
>   amount enough?

That should work, but be careful because with large numbers, or high number of digits, you can easily overflow, and it will give you weird results.

Comment: *you could get the integer part of a floating point number by converting it to an integer type* What if it's too large? Does that ever happen? (I haven't checked, just asking.)

Comment: According to MSDN, double is 64-bit floating point number (or 15-16 digits), so long should be enough.

Comment: @Mehrdad there is an integer type that is the same number of bytes as each floating point type.  It may not always mean using `int`, it may mean using `long`.

Comment: @Servy: Right, but that's not what I meant. Try `unchecked((int)(float)int.MaxValue == int.MaxValue)`.

Comment: @Mehrdad - That line of code makes no sense.  If anything he wants to use an `double` or `decmial` otherwise he would have a method that would accept even a smaller range of numbers then the default method.

Comment: @Mehrdad Notice he said "convert" not "cast".  You need to take the bytes out of an int/float and put it into another int/float.  Just casting doesn't do that.  `int i = int.MaxValue;
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
            float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0);
            System.Console.WriteLine(f);
            int i2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
            System.Console.WriteLine(i2);`

Comment: For that above line of code you can also use a `double` `long` pairing, and you would start with `double`, go to `long`, and then back, rather than starting with the integer type, for the OP's needs.  You could also use an unsafe block, which would likely be more efficient (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11296050/1159478)).

Comment: @Servy: *You're* right, but I don't think this answer is, since it says none of what you said in your comment... Or I'm misunderstanding something... (maybe I should check with long before commenting, sorry)

Comment: @Mehrdad The approach the answerer is attempting is correct, but his method of converting a `double` to a `long` is indeed invalid.

Comment: I noticed that converting rounds the number, but casting doesn't. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Math.Round(12.3456789, 3);
```

[Math.Round Method (Double, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby)

Comment: THanks but internally that also calls the same SplitFractionDouble method.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not "against" that method, I just want to implement my own.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear the reason you think that Truncate should keep the decmial value.

The default method within .NET is described by the following statement:

> The integral part of d; that is, the number that remains after any
>   fractional digits have been discarded.

It seems like what you want to use is either to format the output string of an double/decmial value and/or use the Math.Round(double, int) function instead.

You could just use:

```
double num = 2.22939393; num  = Convert.ToDouble(num.ToString("#0.000"));
```

From one of the duplicate questions:

```
public static decimal TruncateToDecimalPlace(this decimal numberToTruncate, int decimalPlaces) 
{     
       decimal power = (decimal)(Math.Pow(10.0, (double)decimalPlaces));      
       return Math.Truncate((power * numberToTruncate)) / power; 
}
```

I understand this still uses the `Truncate` method.  I only provided this code since you wanted a `Truncate` method that would keep the decmial value of a number and the default built-in `Truncate` method does not.

You could always just use this:

Math.Round does NOT call the `SplitFractionDouble` from what I can tell

```
     private static unsafe double InternalRound(double value, int digits, MidpointRounding mode) {
            if (Abs(value) < doubleRoundLimit) {
                Double power10 = roundPower10Double[digits];
                value *= power10;
                if (mode == MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) {                
                    double fraction = SplitFractionDouble(&value); 
                    if (Abs(fraction) >= 0.5d) {
                        value += Sign(fraction);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // On X86 this can be inlined to just a few instructions
                    value = Round(value);
                }
                value /= power10;
            }
            return value;
          }           


     public static double Round(double value, int digits)
      {
           if ((digits < 0) || (digits > maxRoundingDigits))
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("digits", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_RoundingDigits"));
           return InternalRound(value, digits, MidpointRounding.ToEven);                     
      }

  public static double Round(double value, MidpointRounding mode) {
         return Round(value, 0, mode);
      }

      public static double Round(double value, int digits, MidpointRounding mode) {
          if ((digits < 0) || (digits > maxRoundingDigits))
              throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("digits", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_RoundingDigits"));
          if (mode < MidpointRounding.ToEven || mode > MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) {            
              throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidEnumValue", mode, "MidpointRounding"), "mode");
          }
          return InternalRound(value, digits, mode);                           
      }

      public static Decimal Round(Decimal d) {
        return Decimal.Round(d,0);
      }

      public static Decimal Round(Decimal d, int decimals) {
        return Decimal.Round(d,decimals);
      }

      public static Decimal Round(Decimal d, MidpointRounding mode) {
        return Decimal.Round(d, 0, mode);
      }

      public static Decimal Round(Decimal d, int decimals, MidpointRounding mode) {
        return Decimal.Round(d, decimals, mode);
      }
```

public static Decimal Floor(Decimal d) {
    return Decimal.Floor(d);
  }

[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
  public static extern double Floor(double d);